# iPhone: ASCII Art not displayed properly in Email API from Textview

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextview, textview, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In my iPhone App, I create ASCII Art in UITextView and pass it to Email API.

The alignment of ASCII art is not coming properly.

What should I do to get it in Email API same as created in Textview?

Answer (score 1):

Look at `MFMailComposeViewController` and it's method `setMessageBody:isHTML:`. Use it to create mail with HTML body with font with fixed width (like Courier, ...).

Comment: thanks for reply, I am doing same thing using "Courier New' fonts but when i am passing text to email API it is not coming properly